# How to create the following list/table structure in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, list, listview, listbox

Using WPF and C# how can I create and populate a list/table that is structured as in the example image below? The closest example I was able to find is the [Ultimate ListBox](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Ultimate%20ListBox&referringTitle=Home) within the Extended WPF Toolkit Plus, which is a pay library. I do not think that the Ultimate ListBox control can do exactly what I need. I want my list to be able to group items (as in USA & Canada), and also to have items outside of any group. Could you please tell me how this can be done? Thank you.

[image: My list structure]

Comment: What sort of code do you have already? What are you currently using?

Comment: you need a `hierarchicaldatatemplate` and a `treeview`

Comment: You can use an [Expander](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.expander%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and listbox within it

Comment: Look at list view with a group template

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy to follow solution on [Karl Shifflet's Blog](https://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2009/06/10/wpf-sample-series-listbox-grouping-sorting-subtotals-and-collapsible-regions/) that creates exactly what you want.

[image]